# How to replace selected column in few rows

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [10, 11, 12, 13], 'c2': [100, 110, 120, 130], 'c3': [100, 110, 120, 130], 'c4': ['A', np.nan, np.nan, 'B']})
```

I need to replace row c2 and c3 from another dataframe using column 'c4'

replacer df:

```
df_replacer = pd.DataFrame({'c2': [11, 22], 'c3': [99, 299], 'c4': ['A', 'B']})
```

Below is how I am doing: (Is there a cleaner way to do?)

```
df = df.merge(df_replacer, on=['c4'], how='left')
df.loc[~df.c4.isna(), 'c2_x'] = df['c2_y']
df.loc[~df.c4.isna(), 'c3_x'] = df['c3_y']
df = df.rename({'c2_x': 'c2', 'c3_x':'c3'}, axis=1)
df = df[['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']]
```

Comment: added an answer, does it help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see another way to do it without using the merge, maybe you could do something like this  :

```
df = df.merge(df_replacer, on='c4', how='left', suffixes=('', '_replacer'))
df['c2'] = np.where(df['c2_replacer'].notnull(), df['c2_replacer'], df['c2'])
df['c3'] = np.where(df['c3_replacer'].notnull(), df['c3_replacer'], df['c3'])
df = df.drop(['c2_replacer', 'c3_replacer'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# list of columns to update
cols=['c2', 'c3']

# set the index on column to use for matching the two DF
df.set_index('c4', inplace=True)
df_replacer.set_index('c4', inplace=True)

# use update to replace value in DF
df.update(df_replacer[cols] )

# reset the index
df.reset_index()
```

```
    c4      c1  c2       c3
0   A       10  11.0    99.0
1   NaN     11  22.0    299.0
2   NaN     12  120.0   120.0
3   B       13  22.0    299.0
```